# What is the best way for streaming C++ struct data through TCP socket in Real-time between two projects in the same solution?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, tcp, winsock

Basically I have a struct:

```
typedef struct MyStruct1 {
  vector<MyStruct2> data;
  chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point time_stamp;
} MyStruct1;
```

`MyStruct2` is a struct that contains some opencv data such as: `Point2f`. I want to share this between two projects that are in the same VS solution via TCP socket (because I need reliable connection). Also I tried shared memory but figured out that is not a good way to share complex data structures but for POD. But every time I dereference pointer to `MyStruct1` in the client (project that receives data) my program crashes. Is there any solution to this? Or should I try some other way (and what would that way be)?
The code that I used is here: [server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/complete-server-code) and [client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/complete-client-code) (NOTE: I am not using argv and argc but everything else is the same).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define realtime, is it OK to use some 1000000s cycles to encode your data?

Comment: @Surt The faster the better. Also data doesn't need to be encoded since it won't leave the machine (both processes are executing on the same one)

Comment: a quite simple and portable way is to use remote procedure calling like Apache Thrift or googleRPC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TCP provides a stream of bytes. To send something over TCP, you need to serialize it into a stream of bytes. You can't just write the `MyStruct1` object over the TCP connection. That will never work correctly because the object's internal representation in memory will contain data meaningful only inside the process and that will mean nothing to another process.

Another issue to keep in mind: There might be one entry in that vector. There might be a thousand. How will the receiver know how many bytes to read or know where the object ends?

There are lots of libraries and tools for serialization and deserialization.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have any suggestions for the libraries? And If I do the serialization, could shared memory be possible or should I stick to the socket connection?

Comment: @straus012 I'd suggest doing sockets first. I'd also suggest using some format you are familiar with such as JSON, XML, or lines of text. If you want to get fancier, you can use protocol buffers.

Comment: Okay, thank You very much for Your help. I will put an update once I am done with it.

Answer (score 1):

As long as it is on the same machine and compiled at the same time with all settings the same and the data class is shared on both you can get away with defining an friend `operator<<` and `operator>>` for each type, that are to be send.

Totally untested incomplete code

```cpp
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const MyStruct1 & dt) {
    os << dt.time_stamp << dt.data.size(); // time_stamp might need more magic
    for(auto& val : dt.data) // the MyStruct2 must also have an <<
      os << val;
    return os;
}
```

Write it to a strstream and send the string to the other side, decode it with the `>>`.

Comment: Thank You very much, I eventually narrowed data down, since I didn't need all of it (for now). And now it works pretty much, but now I have a protocol error (10053), maybe because of overflow or something I am not completely sure yet.